# How do I pass both event and props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a function that, when pressing Enter, calls the desired function.
And it looks something like this:

```
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault ();
    handleSubmit ();
  }
}
```

And in the right place I just call it with `onKeyDown = {handleKeyDown}`. But it so happened that I use this function in many places, and somehow I don't want to just repeat the code. (even the names of the handleKeyDown functions are repeated everywhere)

And as a result, I created a separate file and threw the function there, but it did not work, I think it was due to the fact that I passed the **event** and **props** arguments to the function, and when I called this function I did not know what to pass instead of event (I can, of course, pass event to the function where I call it, but there are also props there, and this also does not work).

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to import the event handler, not a component, from a separate file.  I am guessing you are asking about props because you want to pass a function `handleSubmit` from the component. In this case, one option is to pass the callback to a generator when attaching the handler. You might do this as follows.

my_event_handler.js

```
// Returns an event handler with the callback held in its closure
export default function createListener(handleSubmit) {
    return (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault();
            handleSubmit();
        }
    };
}
```

my_component.jsx

```
import createOnKeyHandler from './my_event_handler';

function MyComponent(props) {
    const submitHandler = () => { console.log('woot'); };

    return (
        <input
            placeholder='abc'
            onKeyDown={createOnKeyHandler(submitHandler)}
        />
    );
}
```